# Generalization of identities for values of Chebyshev polynomials

Tags: chebyshev-polynomials

Using the theory of Pell equations and the fact that the discriminant $5$ has both the forms $k^2 + 4$ and $k^2 - 4$, I stumbled across a proof of the identities

$$ (-1)^n T_{2n} (\tfrac{i}{2}) = T_n (\tfrac{3}{2}) $$
$$ (-i)^{2n+1} U_{2n+1} (\tfrac{i}{2}) = U_n (\tfrac{3}{2})$$

for all positive integers $n$.  Here, $i$ is a square root of $-1$ and $T_n$ and $U_n$ denote Chebyshev polynomials of the first and second kinds.

My question is, are there general identities involving Chebyshev polynomials that specialize to these when appropriate inputs are substituted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial quick answer: The Wolfram function site http://functions.wolfram.com/05.04.16.0006.01 lists the relation
$$T_{2n}(z) = (-1)^n T_n(1 - 2 z^2)$$

If you substitute $z=\frac{i}{2}$ you get
$$T_{2n}\left(\frac{i}{2}\right) = (-1)^n T_n\left(1 - 2 (\frac{i}{2})^2\right)= (-1)^n T_n\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)$$
The corresponding entry for $U$ (http://functions.wolfram.com/05.05.16.0004.01) needs some more work than direct substitution (maybe with recurrence formula).

Comment: Thanks!  Didn't know about the Wolfram function site!  It's funny, using the identity they list for U and recurrence as you mention, it is easy to show that $U_{2n+1}(z) = (-1)^n 2z U_n(1-2z^2)$, which seems to me the more natural analogue of the identity for $T$.  I wonder why they don't list it...

Comment: The your $U$ relation and the Wolfram $T$ relation are both listed at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomial_of_the_first_kind#Other_properties

Comment: Don't know how I missed those!